# Downloading a file regularly

Tags: windows, haskell, windows-7, chromium

To help me learn Haskell, I want to write a script for automatically downloading the latest [chromium mini_installer.exe](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) every two days and installing it. Any suggestions?  I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the URL fetching libraries. An example is [download-curl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/download-curl-0.1.4).

Then it is as simple as:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Network.Curl.Download

main = do
   bs <- openURI "http://example.com/example.txt"
   case bs of
      Left err -> error err
      Right d  -> B.writeFile "mydata" d
```

To implement "cron"-like behavior of sleeping for 2 days, you can either use your operating system services, or implement a sleeping mechanism.